# difference between connection.close() and connection= null

Tags: jdbc

If I explicitly close the connection by calling close() on connection object, i have set connection object to null. What is difference in close() and null on connection object?
If i close connection ,still connection object maintained in connection pool?
for e.g.

```
Connection dbConnection=null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
ResultSet rs;
  try {
           Connection dbConnection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:test5","sa", "");
           ...........
           ...........
           dbConnection.close();
           dbConnection=null;
           } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception Occured while fetching All record:Item details start method "
                + e.getMessage());
    } finally {

        try
        {
            if (rs!=null)
            {
                rs.close();
                rs=null;
            }

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error(RESULTSETCLOSEEXCEPTION
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
                preparedStatement=null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(STATEMENTCLOSEEXCEPTION
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
                dbConnection=null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(CONNECTIONCLOSEEXCEPTION
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Is above code is correct way to close connection, prepared statement and resultset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One closes the connection, one sets the connection reference to null.

**If you don't close the connection, you can have a connection leak. It is important to close the connection in a finally block.**

The close() operation closes the connection--**it doesn't do *anything* to the connection reference**. You might not be able to *do* anything with the connection, but it's not null. Once it's closed it can be released back into a collection pool, but that's something different yet again.

**Conclusion::**
**connection.close()** 
 it close the conection with the database and release all the resources.
`***con = null***` - the reference to connection object is deleted in that case if the connection is open then it is still open i.e. resources are not free.

Let me correct if i am getting wrong.

Comment: When you use a connection pool, the connection you get is a proxy or wrapper. Calling `close()` signals to the pool that the connection is to be returned to the pool; it doesn't close the physical connection, but the proxy will behave as if the connection has been closed.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation.

```
close()
Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of
waiting for them to be automatically released.
```

Answer (score 1):

by using `Connection.close()` we can close the resource and we can reuse the connection, because it is go back and stored into the connection pool

and

by making `Connection connection = null` it sense we are free up the connection resource, by this there is no leakage in the memory management, but we can't reuse it.